# Lyx : After Changing numbering, Part appears in regular text in pdf

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, lyx

Lyx. Document class : article (paper)

I wanted numbering for the TOC but without the "Part I" before it.

So I went to Document -> Settings -> Numbering & TOC and changed the numbering column to "no" for all (Part , Section etc.) .

Now when I define some text as `Part` it doesn't show up next to Part I as desired. The problem is that in the PDF the text appears as regular text not big bolded text as normal.

What is strange is that if I define some text as `section` it does appear in its usual big bolded text.

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you're using LyX?

Comment: Do you have to use that document class? There is no such problem with, for example, the normal `article` class.

Comment: I don't have to.. But i prefer to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Torbjørn mention, one solution is to use another class, as  `article` or `extarticle`.

With `paper` class, you can define the part title as `Part*` (instead of  `Part`)followed with a ERT box (`Ctrl+L`)with `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{`*Part title*`}`

Or simply, put all in a ERT as in plain LaTeX:

```
\part*{Part title} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part title}
```